# React app only displays the background color when deployed to github pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, react-dom

I deployed a react app to github pages, but it is only showing my background color and none of the actual components. I followed this guide (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages) to run the terminal commands and to insert the correct code in my json file. I don't get any errors on deploy and when I check the console of my page it doesn't show any errors.

I have my homepage as the github pages link set right under the name.

Here are my scripts in my package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Here is my app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/pages/Home';

function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>

        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component = {Home} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Is something wrong with my ReactDOM? Everything works locally. I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Comment: Can u check the build folder before deploying. Else try deploying in the normal way, like using `git push origin master` after navigating to our build directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either at the `Route` `path`, or once at `Router` `basename` itself, you should add `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` as pointer to your address

```
  <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
```